# Lisp analyze list of atoms and lists

Tags: recursion, lisp, iteration

Im just learning lisp an am asked to write a function called analyze that takes a list and returns a list consisting of symbols 'atom' and 'list'.

For example,
(analyze ‘(a b (c d) e f)) should return (atom atom list atom atom)

Here's what I have so far:

```
(defun analyze(l)                   


(and l
 (if (not(null (atom (first l))
   )
)

'atom 'list
  )
      (or (null (rest l))
          (analyze (rest l)))
      )
)
```

For some reason it always returns T.

Comment: Please format the code correctly. Currently it is unreadable.

Comment: Bad formating defuns the whole thing, turning it into a chore.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your intention was something like this:

```
(defun analyze (l)                   
  (if l                  ; if list is not empty
    (cons                ; add
     (if (atom (car l))  ;  1) a symbol describing the type of (car a)
       'atom 
       'list)
     (analyze (cdr l))))) ; 2) do the same with the rest of the list
```

Your code, correctly indented, looks like this:

```
(defun analyze (l)                   
  (and l
       (if (not (null (atom (first l))))
         'atom 'list)
       (or (null (rest l))
           (analyze (rest l)))))
```

so it is an `and` between

1. l, the list - true if the list is not empty
2. 'atom or 'list - both are symbols, both are logically true
3. true if the rest of the list is empty, or the result of analyse (which is always true)

so it's equivalent to (and t t t ...), the number of t's being the number of items in your list.

Comment: what would be `undf` (not an atom or a list) in Lisp?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list and want to create a new list with the same number of elements, where each element of the new list is somehow calculated from the corresponding element in the original list, the usual way is to use some kind of mapping function.

Here, `mapcar` is the right thing in Common Lisp.

The distinction between *atom* and *list* is not a real dichotomy—the "opposite" of *atom* is *cons*.  There are two interpretations for the exercise:

1. Assume that *list* is meant to mean anything that is not an atom.  Note that `nil` (which is the same as `()`, the empty list) is not a cons but an atom.

   ```
   (defun type-symbol (thing)
     (if (atom thing)
         'atom
         'list))
   ```
2. Assume that *atom* is meant to mean anything that is not a list.  In that case, `nil` would produce `list`.

   ```
   (defun type-symbol* (thing)
     (if (listp thing)
         'list
         'atom))
   ```

To use that with `mapcar`:

```
(defun analyze (list)
  (mapcar #'type-symbol list))
```